# Google BigQuery access in a private environment fails with C# or Python libraries using Private Service Connect

Tags: python, c#, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

we have a special situation where we need to connect to a BigQuery database in the Google Cloud in an environment that is not connected to the internet but can only access private IPs. In order to do so, we have set up a [private service connect endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-service-connect-apis) that allows accessing the BigQuery API via in internal IP. The good news is that this setup works to some extent, meaning that we can use curl to request data from that endpoint. E.g. the following actually works:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" "https://mypscendpoint.p.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/myproject/datasets"
```

However, when using this endpoint with the Python or C# libraries it will run into the following error:

```
 Unhandled exception. System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.

 ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: Connection reset by peer.
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (104): Connection reset by peer
```

This is the code snippet in C# that I was using to test it:

```
using System;
using Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v3;
using Google.Apis.Services;

namespace test1
{
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string projectId = "myproject";
            string[] scopes = new string[] {
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
            };

            var credentials = GoogleCredential.FromFile("mycredentials.json");
            var bqs = new BigqueryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
            {
                BaseUri = "https://mypscendpoint.p.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/",
                HttpClientInitializer = credentials.CreateScoped(scopes)
            });

            var client = new BigQueryClientImpl(projectId,bqs);
            string query = @"SELECT * FROM mydb.mytable LIMIT 100";
            var result = client.ExecuteQuery(query, parameters: null);

            Console.Write("\nQuery Results:\n------------\n");
            foreach (var row in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{row["a"]}: {row["b"]}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the script did not return any results and ran into the above mentioned error. However, when using the same code in an environment with internet access it ran through without any issues. A similar minimal example using Python failed as well.

So my assumption is that the Google BigQuery library calls additional endpoints apart from the one specified in the "BaseUri", which obviously fails if that one is not reachable - most likely for authorization. However, I don't know how to do the authorization without internet access or which additional endpoints I would have to configure using private service connect if necessary.
Does anyone of you have experience with this topic and can give me some hints on that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you use HTTS (secure) TLS is performed before the Request is sent to establish an encryption connection.  You are failing the TLS (which is a type of SSL).  TLS can fail for lots of reasons.  So make sure you are using Net 4.7.2 or later and using operating system for TLS (default condition).  Also make sure your operating system is Windows 10 or later.  And you need a common certificate one the client and server loaded in the user stores.   This should automatically use TLS 1.2 or TLS 1.3 9other versions are obsolete).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I assume that this should not cause the issue since a) I'm using Linux b) have tried running this code in a Docker container both on a system with internet access and one without internet access. It worked perfectly fine on the one with internet but failed on the one without - even though they were sharing the exact same image.

Comment: Issue looks like a certificate issue.  Do you need to use HTTPS on system that is not on Internet?  You could replace HTTPS with HTTP.  For TLS to work you need a common certificate in both client and server.  If Docker works than it can find the certificate.  Docker is probably calling OpenSSL and is working.

Comment: HTTPS is definitely needed to communicate with the BigQuery endpoint. The point is that it's working in a Docker container if I have internet connection but not without - even though I have the exact same system environment (certificates, config etc). That's why I still think that it's related to the fact that the BigQuery libraries use another API endpoint that is not routed via private service connect but only via the internet connection.

Comment: I'm having issues understanding when it is working and not working.  On same machine it should work with both c# and docker.  On same machine if it doesn't work with docker it should not work with c#.  I'm not sure with your description if we have a connection issue with the machine, or code behaves different with docker and c#.  I'm assuming doing comparison you are using the same endpoint.  I think it is a connection issue between the machine and some end points that it fails.  The best way of solving issues it not to use c#.  Instead first get Docker working with endpoint.

Comment: Let's say we have two machines, one that is able to connect to the internet (a) and one that sits behind a firewall and can only communicate with internal IPs (b).
On machine b it does not work either with C# or Docker (or specifically with C# code that lives inside the container) - but it does using the endpoint in a curl request as described above. So the communication with the endpoints works. It therefore has to be related to the C# or Python libraries. On machine a it all works perfectly fine. Docker is just used here to prove that we are having the same environment in a and b.

Comment: You should be using Net 4.7.2 or later.  Then make sure in the csproj (open with notepad) and make sure TLS is not using Net (default is operating system with 4.7.2 or later).  Is python using Net?  Curl is probably using OpenSSL.  If c# is using operating system, than it is an operating system issue.  Linux is the issue (or kernel).  I do not think  it is anything to do with sitting behind a firewall unless one system is using HTTP and the other HTTPS.  We may need to use a sniffer to see if TLS is called in both cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact I found a solution now. The problem was indeed caused by the authentication procedure, which requires a connection to the public endpoint. However following [this description](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#python_2) a token can also be generated offline as signed jwt from the service account information in the json. C# implementation is adapted from [here](https://www.donaldsbaconbytes.com/2016/08/create-jwt-with-a-private-rsa-key/). The modified code then can look like this:

```
using System;
using Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v3;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters;
using Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Security;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using Jose;

namespace test1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string projectId = "myproject";

            const string secretkey = @"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----myPrivateKey-----END PRIVATE KEY-----";
            
            TimeSpan t = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
            int epochtime = (int)t.TotalSeconds;
            int expiry = epochtime + 3600;
            
            var payload = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
            {"iss", "myaccount@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com"},
           {"sub", "myaccount@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com"},
           {"aud", "https://bigquery.googleapis.com/"},
            { "iat", epochtime },
            { "exp", expiry }
            };
            
            var headers = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                { "kid", "myKeyId" }
            };
            var token1 = CreateToken(payload, secretkey, headers);
            

            string[] scopes = new string[] {
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
            };

            var credentials = GoogleCredential.FromAccessToken(token1);
            var bqs = new BigqueryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
            {
                BaseUri = "https://mypscendpoint.p.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/",
                HttpClientInitializer = credentials.CreateScoped(scopes)
            });
            

            var client = new BigQueryClientImpl(projectId,bqs);
            string query = @"SELECT * FROM mydb.mytable LIMIT 100";
    

            var result = client.ExecuteQuery(query, parameters: null);

            Console.Write("\nQuery Results:\n------------\n");
            foreach (var row in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{row["a"]}: {row["b"]}");
            }
 
      }
        
      public static string CreateToken(object payload, string privateKey, Dictionary<string, object> headers)
      {
            string jwt = string.Empty;
            AsymmetricKeyParameter keyPair;
        
            using (var sr = new StringReader(privateKey))
            {
            var pr = new PemReader(sr);
            keyPair = (AsymmetricKeyParameter)pr.ReadObject();
            }
        
            RSAParameters rsaParams = DotNetUtilities.ToRSAParameters((RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters)keyPair);
            using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
            {
            rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParams);
            jwt = Jose.JWT.Encode(payload, rsa, Jose.JwsAlgorithm.RS256, extraHeaders: headers);
            }
        
            return jwt;
       }
   }
}
```